# how can i go from one fragment to another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I want to go from one fragment to another fragment via click on a widgets.
I used this code in the main activity and used onclick in wedget property:

```
public void goOther(View v) {

 Intent go_To_FragmentTwo = new Intent(this, FragmentTwo.class);

 startActivity(go_to_FragmentTwo);

}
```

please with sample code. and please introduce some articles.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: You need to explain the context in more detail. If you hoover the tag you have chosen with your mouse, this explanatory text shows up: 'fragment' is an ambiguous tag, used to refer to numerous technologies. Prefer less ambiguous tags.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do the following:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    String ID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), EventDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra(pid, ID);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

The code below is actually also passing the id of the selected item from one fragment to another, to then display the details according to the value in the ID.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Please consider upvoting this answer if it has helped you :)